# System running services in combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

To see running services i do this:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net start");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String text;

    while ((text=in.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
    in.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(GestionProcesos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Now using GUI designer from NetBeans I want to place each resulting line as an element of an comboBox, how do i do the comboBox.setModel to display a list of the running services?

Comment: What have you tried? What step has you stuck? You know how to get the lines, correct? You understand how to put the lines in a collection, right? The JComboBox tutorial then shows you how to create a model, so where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a `DefaultComboBoxModel<String>` model object.
2. In your while loop above, place the Strings obtained into the model via its `addElement(E anObject)` method.
3. Create your JComboBox with your model.
4. Be careful that your code obeys Swing threading rules, meaning the Process and Stream reading is run off of the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), but all Swing calls are run *on* the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

You're done.

Possible issues:

If you want this list to be changing at run time with services being added and removed, that can be tricky, but with a SwingWorker you could more easily navigate the Swing concurrency issues.